# How to persist large amounts of data through app closure?

Tags: database, xcode, persistence

I have noticed that apps like instagram keep some data persistent through app closures. Even if all internet connection is removed (perhaps via airplane mode) and the app is closed, reopening it still shows the last loaded data despite the fact that the app cannot call any loading functions from the database. I am curious as to how this is achieved? I would like to implement a similar process into my app (Xcode and swift 4), but I do not know which method is best. I know that `NSUserDefaults` can persist app data, but I have seen that this is for small and uncomplicated data, of which mine would not be. I know that I can store some of the data in an internal SQL db, via [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), but some of the data I would like to persist is image data, which I am not sure exactly how to save into SQL. I also know of `Core Data` but after reading through some of the documentation I have become a bit confused as to whether or not it fits my purpose. Which of these (or others?) would be best?
As an additional question, regardless of which persistence method I choose, I feel as though every time the data is actually loaded from the DB (when internet connection is available), which is in the `viewDidLoad`, I would need to be updating the data in the persistent storage in case the internet connection drops. I am concerned that this doubling of my writing procedures will slow the app down? Is there any validity to this concern? Or is it unavoidable anyway?

Comment: Research realm.io, you’re on the right track, though. To persist large amount of data, you have to store it. The storage can become very complex. Realm makes it easy to map objects to disc storage.